# Regular expression to match a string starting with some characters and following with some symblos

Tags: regex

I would like to match a string which starts with character sequence `49`. The string i get to evaluate will be like `49/1.0  or 49/2.0` etc. If I use `^49` it is not matching with the string i receive (ie: `49/1.0`). My expression matches with the string if I receive `49XX` only. I do not sure what are the symbols will follow the  `49` character.

How can i define regular expression for this?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: @shree.pat18 It is javabased server.

Comment: Did you try `^49.*` ?

Comment: Try with this `^49.*`

Comment: @Ratha `^` asserts that we are at the start. `49` matches the string `49` plus `.*` zero or more characters.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks Avinash for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**  `^49.*` this regex.

**explain**

```
^  # start of the string;
49  # match first 49
.*  # match any char in zero to multiple time..
```